# How to find input with specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

**requirement,** 
want to find the input fields that have been entered specific

**html,**

```
<ul class="test-list">
<li>
   <input class="test-input">
</li>
<li>
   <input class="test-input">
</li>
<li>
   <input class="test-input">
</li>
</ul>
```

**example,**

if the user entered "test1", "test2", "test3" in each input field

i tried javascript,

```
$('.test-list').find('.test-input [value="test1"]')
```

and i expect getting the input field that have entered test1, but it returns 0 array :(

i tried `filter()` and witht his it works, but i want to find it directly like the first one.

Comment: var value = $('test-list').find('.test-input').attr('value');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test-input` is classname and not tagname. also you need to remove the space in `name-value` selector and `.test-input`. You need to use:

```
$('.test-list').find('.test-input[value="test1"]');
```

you can also narrow down selector to:

```
$('.test-list [value=test1]');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M93WT/)**

Comment: Doesn't required `$('.test-list')` ?

Comment: @Canna: did you removed the space in between selector.

Answer (score 1):

try

you missed `.class selecor`

```
$('.test-list').find('.test-input [value="test1"]')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pyqA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

- Your code doesn't work because you are missing a dot
- Use `find()` to descend into child nodes and a `[value="x"]` selector

## [Solution:](http://jsfiddle.net/4pyqA/)

```
$('.test-list').find('.test-input[value="test1"]');
```

**Resources:**

- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [Value selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

doing [value="test1"] is not rational solution.
what if an element has no "value" attribute?
so I'll do it like this:

```
$('.test-list').find('.test-input').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == 'test1') {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.test-list').find('.test-input[value="test1"]')
```